# Meaning of "Consistent state" in C programming

Tags: c

What does my professor mean when he says "Variable 1 and variable 2 are supposed to be in consistent state"? What does "being in consistent state" mean?

Comment: We are no claivoyants. How would we know what your professor means? I'm pretty sure he will not bite you, so why not ask him directly?

Comment: "Grrrrrrrrr... *>SNAP<* ....

Comment: What was the context of the statement?  What kind of program was your professor discussing?  Without that information, we can't even make a good guess.

Answer (score 0):

The wording does not sound familiar to me, but perhaps that was the professor's intention.
I think that he means that the variables have been initialised. But he could also mean that in e.g. a multithreaded context, the variables are set while holding a mutex. Or that the variables are not volatile.
Without more context, it is hard to guess what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are writing the navigation software for a ship.  Suppose your interface to the GPS receiver is a pair of functions

```
double get_latitude();
double get_longitude();
```

Suppose you write this loop to keep a display of the ship's position up-to-date:

```
double lat, lon;
while(1) {
    lat = get_latitude();
    printf("position: %.4f, %.4f\n", lat, lon);
    lon = get_longitude();
    sleep(1);
}
```

But this code has an obvious bug: it prints the latitude along with the longitude from 1 second ago.  If the ship is moving, the positions will be wrong, because the `lat` and `long` variables are not in a consistent state.

A related term is *loop invariant*.

Comment: Also, on the first cycle, it prints an uninitialized variable — `lon` does not yet have a value assigned.